# Edge renders german dates as Skype links

Tags: html, hyperlink, microsoft-edge

I have an JSF application with a primefaces `dataTable`. In a column there is a date rendered in german format `dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:dd`. Unfortunately in microsofts edge browser this date is shown as a link. When the link is clicked Skype is opened. Can I suppress this? How? Chrome and FF does not show a link. I know this is probably no problem of JSF or primefaces but I think it could be useful to mention which technologies are used.

Comment: To test if its is PrimeFaces or JSF related, output it in a plain `h:outputText`. If it fails there, add the html tag to the question and remove JSF and PrimeFaces (questions will be found anyways if formulated correctly)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't need phone number detection at all in your page, you can suppress the feature by adding the tag `<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">`

Answer (score 0):

For completeness - You can also:

(1) ...disable that detection feature on a per-element basis

```
<p x-ms-format-detection="none">01.12.2019</p>
```

(2) ...use javascript to do the disabling

```
document.querySelectorAll('p').forEach( 
    function(a) { a.setAttribute('x-ms-format-detection', 'none') } 
)
```